# JavaPairRDD to DataFrame in Apache Spark with java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some document file, I try to read data and then zip with index using zipWithIndex() function follow:

```
    JavaRDD<String> rawTextRDD = sc.textFile("demo.txt");
    JavaPairRDD<String, Long> zipIndex = rawTextRDD.zipWithIndex();
```

After that value of zipIndex is a JavaPairRDD containing key-value pair, look like ["This is the beautiful picture", 0], ["This is another picture", 1].

But now, I want to convert zipIndex into DataFrame using:

```
DataFrame docDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zipIndex, TextId.class);
```

function createDataFrame does not accept parameter zipIndex (TextId is a class with 2 property: String text and int docId).

I also have a code in Scala, and it run very well. Please refer to this:

```
val rawTextRDD = sc.textFile("demo.txt")
val docDF = rawTextRDD.zipWithIndex.toDF("text", "docId")
```

If there is any solution. Please help me to resolve. Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do here `sqlContext.createDataFrame(zipIndex, TextId.class);` ?

Comment: I don't see any reason why would it accept `zipIndex`. It is a `JavaPairRDD<String, Long>` not `JavaRDD<TextId>`.

Comment: @eliasah I think it is simple type mismatch and `zipIndex` should be mapped to `JavaRDD<TextId>` but I am to lazy to check :) What do you think?

Comment: @zero323 I have tried to check it. The Java API is making me fetch the rdd from the rawTextRDD to create and RDD of Tuple<String,Object> which is weird. I will investigate more on it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks zero323 and @eliasah, I have re-checked Java API, function createDataFrame does not accept parameter JavaPairRDD<String, Long>. It is my mistake. Thank you very much, I will try to convert from  JavaPairRDD<String, Long> to JavaRDD<TextId> :D

Answer (score -1):

Try this: DataFrame docDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(zipIndex.values(), TextId.class);

Comment: It might be good to explain why this change solves the problem.